# Real valued continuous function is the unique difference of two positive functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity, c-star-algebras

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. I want to prove that we have a **unique** decomposition

$$f= f_1 - f_2$$

where $f_1 f_2 = 0 = f_2 f_1$.

where $f_1, f_2: X \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous **positive** functions. I managed to show the existence, but I'm not sure how I can prove the uniqueness.

Comment: Intuitively, thanks to continuity on some interval $I$ then $f=f_1$ since $f_2=0$ there. Similarly $f=g_1$ on $J$. So $f_1=g_1$ on $I\cap J$. you may want to show that $I=J$ in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniqueness easily follows from the condition $f_1f_2=0$. This means that for every $x \in X$ you have $f_1(x)=0$ or $f_2(x)=0$ and $f(x)=f_1(x)-f_2(x)$, this implies if $f(x)>0$ then $f(x)=f_1(x)$ while $f_2(x)=0$ and vice versa $f(x)<0$ implies $f(x)=-f_2(x)$. If $f(x)=0$ then $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ and their product must be zero: that is $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=0$.

Existence is an easy application of the pasting lemma, since you said you already proved it I won't go into detail.

Edit: since you asked in the comments I am going to explain how the pasting lemma can be used to provide the maps. Since $f$ is continuous $N=f^{-1}((-\infty, 0])$ and $P=f^{-1}([0, +\infty))$ are both closed subsets of $X$. The pasting lemma states that if you have two continuous function $g,h$ defined on closed subsets of a topological space and they coincide on the intersection then gluing them together you get a continuous function on the whole space.

In our case you can take $g\colon P \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be $g=f|_P$ and $h\colon N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be the zero function. Applying the lemma you obtain a function which is your $f_1$.

Comment: Just one clarification: Existence: One can check that $f_1 = \max\{f,0\}$, $f_2 = \max\{-f,0\}$ works. How does this use pasting lemma? More like composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: @user745578 You can see it as both. If you don't want to show in general that $\max$ is a continuous function, you can also note that $$f_1(x)=\begin{cases} f(x)& x  \in f^{-1}[[0,\infty)] \\ 0 & x \in f^{-1}[(-\infty, 0]]\end{cases}$$ and both domain parts are closed as $f$ is continuous. Similarly for $f_2$.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma. Thanks. Now I get it

Comment: @user745578 You're welcome. The usual notation (in any algebraic lattice, like $C(X)$ is, is $f^+$ and $f^-$, the positive and negative parts of $f$. $f^+ + f^- = |f|$ as well. Gillman and Jerrison treat it very briefly in the classic book "rings of continuous functions" as useful background facts.

Answer (score 2):

Let us show that $f_1(x)$ must be $\max \{f(x),0\}$. First let $f(x) \geq 0$. Then $f_1(x) \geq f_2(x) \geq 0$. If $f_1(x)=0$ we get $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=0$ so $f_1(x)=0=\max \{f(x),0\}$.

Otherwise $f_2(x)=0$ (because $f_1(x)f_2(x)=0$) so $f_1(x)=f(x)= \max \{f(x),0\}$.

Now let $f(x) <0$. Then $f_1(x) <f_2(x)$. This implies that  $f_1(x)=0$ (by hypothesis and the fact that $f_2(x) >0$). Hence $f_1(x)=0= \max \{f(x),0\}$.

We have proved that $f_1$ is unique. It follows that $f_2=f_1-f$ is also uniquue.

Comment: Why must $f_1(x) \geq f_2(x)?$

Comment: @user745578 Because I am assuming that $f\geq 0$ in the first case.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the answer!